# how to do method level authorization for Springboot application which is developed as microservices?

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, methods, controller

I have created authentication service and it was implemented in other services. now I want to do method-level authorization.

This is my  Security configuration class  of  one of my microservice which is developed using springboot.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true,securedEnabled = true,jsr250Enabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
               
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

And this is an end point (save method ) in my controller class. I want to add here method level security..
I have A user As a "USER_ADMIN"

```
@PostMapping(value = "/save")
    public Object save(@ModelAttribute Course course) {
        try {
            Course dbCourse = courseService.save(course);
            log.info("course saved method called");
            log.info("HttpStatus===" + new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK));
            return course;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.info("Exception: " + e);
            log.error("occur an error when viewing all courses");
            return new ResponseEntity<Course>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring secuity @PreAuthorize to do method level Authorization
Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html